# Magento 2 add new custom container above <main> tag

Tags: magento2, layout, custom, page-layouts

I want to add new custom container the `<main>` tag.

I have created the custom layout for my custom page design. I have created in the below directory:

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\custom_layout.xml**

And than assigned this in the `layouts.xml` like below:

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\page_layout\custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="custom_layout">
        <label translate="true">Custom Layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

And assigned this layout to my custom page. It's spearing in the frontend design, I just want to add new div container above the `<main>`.

How I can add new `div container` above the `<main>`?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <container name="{your_name}" htmlTag="div" before="main.content">
        <!-- must have content to display -->
        <block name="{some_content_block}" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Be aware that the container will only display if it has content!

Reference: `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml` -> here you will find your `main.content` container wrapped in `page.wrapper` container thus you have to place your new container into `page.wrapper` with the before attribute to make it appear before `main.content`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <container name="root">
        <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
        <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-wrapper">
            <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
            <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
                <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
                <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                    <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
            <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
        </container>
    </container>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Preferred way is to edit in theme's default.xml file. You may create or edit the default.xml file at path **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

If one wants to add container div under column div, should try this.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
           <referenceContainer name="columns">
                <container name="container" label="" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container" />
            </referenceContainer>        
           <move element="main" destination="container" before="-"/>
        </body>
</page>
```

Comment: This answer was helpful thank you.

I wanted to put the search bar as a child of the navigation sections.

       <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <container name="toptop" label="" htmlTag="div" htmlId="toptop" />
        </referenceContainer>
       <move element="navigation.sections" destination="toptop" after="-"/>
       <move element="top.search" destination="toptop" after="-"/>